# ionic 4 - change navigation transition direction dynamically

Tags: angular, transition, router, ionic4

I want to be able to control the navigation transition direction dynamically.

in this post I found out how i can enforce either android or ios default transitions.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/page-transition-direction-in-ionic-4/148518/5

```
    IonicModule.forRoot({
        rippleEffect: false,
        // TODO:
        // navAnimation: override here
    }),
```

Is there a way i can set the transition direction from inside a component before the transition starts?

Comment: which animation do you want while pushing to next view?

Comment: Seems like router-outlet does have such a property (animate: boolean, animation: Animation), but docs are unclear on how to actually use that;/ https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router-outlet

Comment: I want to be able to switch between sideways transitions when the navigation context is on the same hierarchical level (like slide behavior) while using the up und down transitions for navigating deeper

Comment: Hey man, did you find a solution?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Yes see my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this issue and posted a medium article

https://medium.com/@hanche2001/how-to-change-between-android-and-ios-page-transitions-dynamically-in-ionic-ec1256a692f5

TLDR

IonicModule.forRoots allows you to configure and force a predefined transition animation with the navAnimation function

The navAnimation function receives a reference of the entering and leaving page as well as the ion-router-outlet used

You can write a custom function that checks either the ion-router-outlet or the entering page for any DOM attribute and return which page transition you want to use

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** I am not currently using this solution as I experienced a couple small weird bugs.  Perhaps this could still help someone though...

Just ran into this today.  My use case was pagination.  In iOS mode, for example, I wanted the page to turn forward if the new page clicked was higher, else I wanted the page to turn back.  Yet, in both cases I wanted to go forward in history.

The solution is actually super simple.  [Here are the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/) for `NavController`.  Here is my one-liner:

```
this.navController.navigateForward(`/blog/home/${page}`,
  { queryParamsHandling: 'merge', animationDirection: page > this.currentPage ? 'forward' : 'back' });
```

So, basically just use `NavController` - which still works with the Angular router - and provide the `animationDirection` option.

Using `navigateForward` is the right move if you want it so regardless what direction they go, they are still going forward in history and can go back to the previous view.  There is also `navigateBack` as well.

Comment: you can only animate either horizontally (default ios) or vertically (default android) with the ionic navController api. you can't controll all 4 directions

Comment: True.  Also, I experienced a couple of small bugs with NavController: one with a white screen after going back after a 'back' animation on iOS and one with query param behavior not being honored.  It may be worth opening issues for those.

Answer (score 0):

I use the ionic navController and the options nav.navigateForward, nav.navigateRoot, and nav.navigateBack. These hook into the angular router perform the necessary directional animation.

It's not well-documented, but this has some good examples: https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-latest-angular-routing-in-ionic-4-application/#more-2025